# ERROR in necessary_column validator: `prompt` column/key is missing

Tags: python, openai-api, fine-tuning, large-language-model

I was preparing my `.csv` data with CLI ant this error keeps coming up, but my columns are already named `prompt` and `completion`. How can I fix it?

I tried changing it to " 'prompt' " and " 'completion' ", I don't know what's wrong